# How can I explicitly signal completion of a Flowable in RxJava?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I'm trying to create a `Flowable` which is wrapping an `Iterable`. I push elements to my `Iterable` periodically but it seems that the **completion** event is implicit. I don't know how to signal that processing is complete. For example in my code:

```
    // note that this code is written in Kotlin
    val iterable = LinkedBlockingQueue<Int>()
    iterable.addAll(listOf(1, 2, 3))

    val flowable = Flowable.fromIterable(iterable)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())

    flowable.subscribe(::println, {it.printStackTrace()}, {println("completed")})

    iterable.add(4)

    Thread.sleep(1000)

    iterable.add(5)

    Thread.sleep(1000)
```

This prints:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   completed

I checked the source of the `Flowable` interface but it seems that I can't signal that a `Flowable` is complete explicitly. How can I do so? In my program I publish events which have some delay between them and I would like to be explicit when to `complete` the event flow.

**Clarification**:
I have a long running process which emits events. I gather them in a queue and I expose a method which returns a Flowable which wraps around my queue. The problem is that there might be already elements in the queue when I create the Flowable. I will process the events only once and I know when the flow of events stops so I know when I need to complete the Flowable.

Comment: @akarnokd you are a core contributor to RxJava right?

Comment: Yes. What do you want to achieve? Push items into a queue and replay it to subscribers or multicast items as they are generated imperatively? If so, please look at the `Subject` concept of RxJava (also `FlowableProcessor` in v2).

Comment: I have a long running process which emits events. I gather them in a queue and I expose a method which returns a `Flowable` which wraps around my queue. The problem is that there might be already elements in the queue when I create the `Flowable`. I will process the events only once and I know when the flow of events stops so I know when I need to `complete` the `Flowable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.fromIterable` is the wrong way to create a `Flowable` for your use case.
Im not actually clear on what that use case is, but you probably want to use `Flowable.create()`  or a `PublishSubject`

```
val flowable = Flowable.create<Int>( {
    it.onNext(1)
    it.onNext(2)
    it.onComplete()
}, BackpressureStrategy.MISSING)

val publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
val flowableFromSubject = publishSubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.MISSING)
//This data will be dropepd unless something is subscribed to the flowable.
publishSubject.onNext(1)
publishSubject.onNext(2)
publishSubject.onComplete()
```

Of course how you deal with back-pressure will depend on the nature of the source of data.

Comment: What class did you use for `emitter`? I will call the `onNext` and `onComplete` outside from the `Flowable.create`'s scope so I need to store a reference to it elsewhere.

Comment: With `Flowable.create` the emiiter is provided by RXJava, so dealing with the scope can be tricky, I have added an example using a publish subject which might be easier for you.

Comment: Is there a version which "remembers" the `onNext` calls if I don't have a subscriber yet? Currently if I call `onNext` before I `subscribe` to the `Flowable` the values are lost.

Comment: Ok I found it it is `ReplaySubject`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like suggested by akarnokd, [ReplayProcessor](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/processors/ReplayProcessor.java) do exactly what you want. Replace `iterable.add(item)` with `processor.onNext(item)`, and call `processor.onComplete()` when you are done.

Comment: `ReplaySubject` was the solution thanks! I ended up not needing the `Iterable` at all.