# RxJava2, completing a cold source (Flowable) explicitly

Tags: java, rx-java2

Did search first, found no good answer, so there we go :)

Trying to apply RxJava2 to the existing pipelines we use at work - both hot and cold sources. While stopping a hot one (wrapped with Flowable.create) is straightforward, the other case appears to be trickier.
In short, I want to be able to make the source finish **and** drain the items already in the pipeline before becoming disposed.
This is what I came up with (takeUntil() and a special item to end the sequence), but the question about there being a better way remains

(Flowables.repeatCallable is an extension from https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions which suits my case better than stock methods)
buffer/map/reduce are just there to create a resemblance of *some* processing :)

```
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Disposable d = Flowables.repeatCallable(() -> {
                return stop.get() ? -1 : counter.getAndIncrement();
            }
    )
            .doOnCancel(() -> {
                debug("cancelled");
            })
            .doOnRequest(l ->
                    debug(Long.toString(l) + " values requested")
            )
            .takeUntil(val -> val < 0)
            .filter(val -> val >= 0)
            .buffer(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler, 15, ArrayListSupplier.asCallable(), true)
            .map(list -> {
                debug("received " + list.size() + " items: " + list);
                return list.size();
            })
            .reduce(0, (sum, item) -> sum + item)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(i -> debug("Items received: " + i));
```

and then, at some point:

```
    stop.set(true);
    while (!d.isDisposed()) {
        // wait
    }
```

This does complete upon receiving the stop signal and the final onSuccess handler executes.
Oddly enough, onCancel handler is being called twice:
first from

```
onNext:69, FlowableTakeUntilPredicate$InnerSubscriber (io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable)
```

and then from

```
cancel:100, FlowableTakeUntilPredicate$InnerSubscriber (io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable)
dispose:543, FlowableBufferTimed$BufferExactBoundedSubscriber (io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `buffer()` calls `cancel` upon receiving `onComplete()` unnecessarily.

Comment: look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176634/how-can-i-explicitly-signal-completion-of-a-flowable-in-rxjava
I think you can use a ReplayProcessor

Comment: It needs to be a cold source, frhack, with supply controlled by the downstream demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use flow control for a purpose it wasn't really meant for. You consequently get snarled up because `buffer()` defeats all your flow control mechanics.

Similarly, `takeUntil()` will unsubscribe from your observable as soon as the predicate succeeds. There is no "draining" at that point, as all the acceptable values have already passed through to the downstream.

Trying to use the `stop` as a control on the observable mixes modes, and, again, doesn't do what you think it does.

Introducing a `ReplayProcessor` or similar intermediary will allow the cold source to keep sending data even when no subscriptions are active.

Ultimately, you have to separate out your concerns. There are several good tutorials on converting cold observables to hot observables.

Comment: I don't need it to send data when no one's listening. It is a cold source and I want it to stay that way :) Think of it as a toilet paper roll vs a teletype machine. You only want as much of paper as you need.

As for takeUntil(), it's not a requirement, it's just a way I've found to close the valve on a cold source when I want to because it's unbounded (more or less) otherwise

Comment: It is still not clear what your requirement is. Your source code mixes a number of modes and doesn't match your narrative.

Comment: I know that external stop button doesn't match the "pull" processing pattern very well, hence my original question. But the need is there to stop production of new items on an external event (Spring context shutdown, for example)